# I am facing a small bump printing number pyramids , still a newbie to php and programming

Tags: php

What i want to print is

1

3 5

7 9 11

With my current code , that is ...

```
<?php

function Odd($limit='20'){

$c = 1;
while($c <= $limit){
if ($c % 2!=0){
echo $c ;
echo "<br/>";
}
$c++ ;

}
}
Print Odd();
?>
```

i am getting 
1
3
5
7
9
11

Can someone please guide me the right way ?

Comment: `for ($c = 1; $c < 20; $c += 2) { ... }`

Comment: Uhm, this is correct, just copied your code and here is my output: `1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19`

Comment: This is the output i am getting with your loop 1
123
12345
1234567
123456789
1234567891011
12345678910111213
123456789101112131415
1234567891011121314151617
12345678910111213141516171819

Comment: When i am putting it in the second for loop ...dis is the output coming .......1
13
13
135
135
1357
1357
13579
13579
1357911
1357911
135791113
135791113
13579111315
13579111315
1357911131517
1357911131517
135791113151719
135791113151719

Comment: This is really basic you must figure out yourself to sharpen your basic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaah ... ok.^^ Now i got it.

Its pretty easy: You need another variable which counts up and one which limits the breakposition. Looks like this:

```
<?php

function Odd($limit='40'){

    $c = 1;
    $count = 0;
    $break = 1;

    while($c <= $limit){
        if ($c % 2!=0){
            echo $c . " ";
            $count++;

            if($count === $break) {
                echo "<br/>";
                $break++;
                $count = 0;
            }
        }
        $c++ ;

    }
}
Print Odd();
?>
```

Output till 40:

```
1
3 5
7 9 11
13 15 17 19
21 23 25 27 29
31 33 35 37 39
```

Edit: Code for your new request:

```
<?php

function Odd($limit='40'){

$c = 1;
$count = 0;
$break = 1;

while($c <= $limit){
        echo $c . " ";
        $count++;
        if($count === $break) {
            echo "<br/>";
            $break++;
            $count = 0;
        }
    $c++ ;

    }
}
Print Odd();
?>
```

Comment: No prob, consider marking this answer as top answer. I WANT REPUTATION! :D

Comment: Will select it as the correct answer when the 5 mins time limit put by SO gets over :)

Comment: What change should i do to this so that it displays the following ?  1 23 456 78910 ? Plz help

Comment: Well cmon, thats easy.^^ Just remove the whole if condition `if ($c % 2!=0){`.^^ So it will print every number. Ill add the code as edit.

Comment: thanks again , maybe i shud start experimenting a bit more with loops :)

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to output something like that:

1
3 5 
7 9 11 
13 15 17 19

Here is my solution:

```
function Odd($limit='20'){
$c = 1;$some_array = array();
while($c <= $limit){
    if ($c % 2!=0){
        $some_array[]=$c; 
    }
    $c++ ;

}
return $some_array;

}

$array = Odd();
$nr =0; 
$j=1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
echo $value.'&nbsp;';$nr++;
if($nr==$j){
    echo '<br />';
    $nr=0;
    $j++;
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What change should i do to this so that it displays the following ? 1 23 456 78910 ? Plz help

Comment: in the function Odd() you should remove the  **if ($c % 2!=0)** clause. So the function is something like that:function Odd($limit='20'){
$c = 1;$some_array = array();
while($c <= $limit){
    $some_array[]=$c; 
    $c++ ;
}
return $some_array;

}

Answer (score 0):

From your question it Seems you are really new to programming so before writing any program first of all observe the question properly:

For example for the question above it is clear that is an triangle of odd numbers.

now the number of odd numbers on each row is equal to the row
i.e 1st row contains 1 number ,2nd contains 2 and it continues...

Now what we do is take an variable to count the no of rows say $row and the other will be `$limit` .

```
<?php
function odd($limit){
    $row=1;
    $current_number=1;
    while($current_number<=$limit){
        for($i=1;$i<=$row;$i++){
            echo $current_number." ";
            $current_number=$current_number+2;//incrementing numbers by 2 if you want to increment by 1 i.e print all numbers replace 2 by 1
        }
        $row++;
        echo "<br/>";//for new line
    }
}
```

To run above function you need to call it and pass the value of `$limit`.To do it just type anywhere outside of this function.

```
odd(20);
```

**Watch this running [here](http://3v4l.org/0Cgnb):**

Comment: You need to call the function check I have updated my answer.